# [Shift]+[F1] not working in putty telnet sessions

Tags: putty, telnet, keys, shortcut

***Update:***
I configured putty (Windows 8; x64) to send exactly the same data as an old 16 bit Hyperterminal (Windows XP). I tested it using Wireshark.
But still the Software on the Suse Server does not respond correctly to my typing of Fn keys.

What could possibly be wrong? Wat am I missing here?

---

I just switched from a 16 bit terminal client to Putty (on Windows 8 Pro x64) and ran into a Problem which I cannot solve on my own:

I need the Keyboard shortcut [Shift]+[F1] inside the Server-Session. But whenever I type the two keys, Putty just removes the selected character form the screen.

Wireshark told me the transmitted Data is "\033[Y" and the "Poor Woman's Telnet Server" (ShellIo Java Library) calls it "Unrecognized ESC sequence with char 89 Y".

How can I send this escape sequence from the putty client? I configured putty to SCO Keyboard Settings and it sends the right sequences (so it's shown in Wireshark). But the Server does not respond to F1 to F12.

Comment: Do a packet capture using the old client, figure out exactly what key sequence is sent when you press shift-F12?  Then configure Putty to do that?  We can't really help you given the information you have posted so far.  You haven't told us anything about the software/OS that you are connecting to.

Comment: It seems that the original Client sends [ESC]+[ ]. What is this in putty? Or can I map another key to this combination somewhere?

Comment: May be it was [[]+[Y] instead. How can I type this?

Comment: No idea.  But you can/should edit those details and questions into your question.  Did you find that information through a capture, or from some documentation?  You might also want to consider adding details about the HOST OS, and software you are using, if it isn't something custom.

Comment: I will expand my question after work tomorrow, maybe I can read something using wireshark. The informations above are from the old Client configuration.

Comment: I have Extended the question by adding info from Wireshark and an alternative Telnet Server.

Comment: Another update is right in my opening question.

Answer (score 1):

try following: [Configuring PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.4.3)

Comment: Thanks, but I read this page over and over and tried everything useful (as far as I can judge). Putty now runs in the Xterm R6 mode, so far the only one fully compatible with the server software.

Comment: PuTTY doesnt appear to have any code that allows it to put out the proper Shift+Function key mappings (such as Shift+F5 should be `\e[15;2~`). I work around this by forking and recompiling PuTTY

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Terminal > Keyboard` in the configuration window of PuTTY, change the `Function keys and keypad` setting to `Xterm R6`.